# send message to specific contact through WhatsApp from my android app not working in 4.4.4

Tags: android

I am developing an android app and I need to send a message to specific contact from WhatsApp. Code not working in android version 4.4. I tried this code:

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number) { 
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number); 
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri); 
  i.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); 
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "")); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
private void openWhatsApp(String id) {
Cursor c =    
  getSherlockActivity().getContentResolver().query(
  ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID },       

  ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
    new String[] { id }, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     

 Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" + c.getString(0)));

 startActivity(i);
 c.close();
 }
```

Where id is what's app uri like

0987654321@s.whatsapp.net

Comment: Thanks for reply  but it not work for unknown number. I need to send a message to unknown contact

Comment: @sarikakashid Whatsapp is opening tha chat history, but doesn't take the text and send it according to your code